# Can I import fields into freeform?

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, fields, datagrab, import

I'm overhauling a legacy ee 1.7 site and they use freeform pretty heavily; currently they have about 170 freeform fields(!) - is there a way to import them into a fresh install of freeform? I haven't tried to go through an upgrade path with this and I'm using a clean 2.10 build with datagrab to pull content in.

I don't want to pull in the legacy freeform data particularly but if I could import all those fields it would save a lot of time/sanity!

Answer (score 0):

If you were on the latest/last version of Freeform 3 and then updated to Freeform 4, there is a Migration Tool under the **Utilities** tab in the Freeform module in the CP that should allow you to transfer your Freeform 3.x data and fields over to Freeform 4.x, which is EE2-compatible.